# Filter timeline by only vote summaries

Tags: feature-request, timeline

When viewing a question's timeline there are two options for what to display:

"Hide vote summaries" and "Show vote summaries".

[image: Screenshot of options]

I would find it useful to be able to view *only* vote summaries. If I want to track the voting progression on a particular question, especially one which has lots of activity, I have to sift through lines of irrelevant details to find the ones that are the vote summaries:

[image: Screenshot showing the irrelevant details]

Can there be an option to only view the vote summaries?

Comment: Perhaps someone could come up with a userscript for this.

Comment: Sam's [Post Timeline Filters](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/README.md#post-timeline-filters) userscript ([GitHub](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/PostTimelineFilters.user.js)) ([install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/PostTimelineFilters.user.js)) already does this.